# Creating a browser tab that return data from database with flask, Template inheritance

Tags: python, html, database, header

I would like to create a header with 3 browser tab ( Home, About and Query) to use a database.
My database is about miRNA ans other informations.
My goal is that I want user to search for miRNA, and ask it to tell us information about it and then to obtain the results in a table.
My database is available in mySQL.
I created 4 folders: index.html , query.html , base.html and myapp.py
I don't know what's wrong with my code.
Thank you for your help!

This my code (myapp.py):

```
def queryForMiRN(mirna):
    sqlcmd= 'SELECT prediction.miRNA, Transcript.TranscriptID, Transcript.GeneSymbol, Prediction.UTRStart, Prediction.UTREnd FROM mydb.Prediction INNER JOIN mydb.Transcript ON Prediction.TranscriptID = Transcript.TranscriptID WHERE miRNA =%s'
    cursor.execute(sqlcmd, (mirna,))
    results = []
    for row in cursor:
        row = [str(item) for item in row]
        results.append(tuple(row))
    conn.commit()
    print(results)
    return(results)


def getResultsHTML(results):
    Header = '''<head>
    <img src = http://www.targetscan.org/vert_72/images/tlogo_vert_72.gif>
    </head>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <thead>
    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">miRNA</th>
    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">TranscriptID</hr>
    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">Gene Symbol</hr>
    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">UTR start</hr>
    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">UTR end</hr>
    </thead>
    </tr>'''
    Body=''
    for i in results:
        Body += '<tr> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">%s</td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">%s</td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">%s</td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">%s</td><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px 15px;">%s</td> </tr>'%(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4])
    html = Header + Body
    return(html)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    mirna = 'mml-miR-23b-3p'
    results = queryForMiRNA(mirna)
    html = getResultsHTML(results)
    return html
```

This is my code for Query.html:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ mytitle }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 

<form method="GET" action="{{ url_for('Query') }}">
    <label for="name">Choose your miRNA: </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your miRNA" id="mirna">
    <input type="submit">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

This is my code for base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>  |
    <a href="{{ url_for('Query') }}">Query</a>  |
    <a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About the database</a>
  <p>



  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code for index.html:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ mytitle }} {% endblock %}
{% block content %} {{ mycontent }} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: "I don't know what's wrong with my code" neither do we because you haven't explained what it isn't doing. Is there an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @roganjosh well spotted :) !!! That's what I call "reading between the lines" :D

Comment: @roganjosh When I click on Query, it shows me "Choose your miRNA" and then I enter the miRNA that I want and nothing happened. Whatever I put into the case "choose your miRNA" it shows me nothing